# Unable to sign iPhone app with distribution certificate

Tags: iphone, code-signing

I have struggled every step of the way with the process of submitting to the appstore. I am now at the point where it asked if I wanted to use the distibution certificate I have in Xcode.

I selected yes and I get an error as below. What is the problem with this? please help. I have stuggled more to setup this process than to develop my app.

```
The iPhone “**********” doesn’t have the provisioning profile with which the application was signed.



Click “Install and Run” to install the provisioning profile “#######” on “**********” and continue running “$$$$$$$.app”.
```

If I click install and run it just says it cannot install blah blah

Comment: Did you remember to register that specific device and create a provisioning profile with that device ID included? This often happens when you use a new device but forgot to recreate the provisioning profile.

Comment: I would suggest a better title or you will probably not get good responses.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean but I have been and can still test correctly on my device when it is in debug mode and the app works perfectly, as soon as I try release mode I get this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Organizer in Xcode (Window > Organizer).

1. Does your iPhone's name appear there?  If not, is your phone plugged in :)?  Also, some people have had this issue when installing multiple versions of XCode - if your phone also doesn't show up in iTunes, reinstall iTunes to address this.
2. If it does show up, click on it.  Look at the provisioning profiles.   What do you see there?  Do you see one that matches your app?

Comment: I see two provisioning items, my first one and one called new, which I dont know if I use. Should the distro on ebe there? because I dont see it? What do you mean by matches my app? I have the two which I named before the app existed? I see my app name along with all my other app in the applications section, but not in the provisioning section. regards

Comment: Okay, that sounds like an issue.  Have you created an App ID on Apple's developer page yet?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your build configurations are correct for the following:

- Distribution (which i think you've got)
- Device (for whichever device you're building for)

Comment: I have been following this tutorial http://www.idev101.com/code/Distribution/build.html
 and I cant get it to work. I have the base sdk set to iOS 4 and set the code signing(2 fields) to iphone distibutor but get the error.

Answer (score -4):

There are very detailed and clear instructions provided.  Start all over at #1, and follow them through carefully one by one. Check each step several times to make sure you've done it right.

Comment: This is basically a thinly veiled RTFM. Just down vote the question if you don't find it useful. The assumption is that OP is having problems precisely with what you are suggesting.

Comment: You're welcome to that opinion, but it is valid advice, and is what solved similar problems for me.